# Find a point on an outer concentric circle in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, trigonometry

I've got two concentric circles with their centers at (centerX,centerY). The inner circle has a radius of 100 and the outer circle has a radius of 400. If take a point on the circumference of the inner circle, I can draw a  line from the center to that point. Let's call that point x1,y1). I now want to continue that radius out to the outer concentric circle and calculate the position of that outer point (x2,y2).

I'm adding a 3px 'dot' just to show where x1, y1 is on the screen. (Subquestion: I can't see it...not sure why.)

This is what I'm trying:

```
    var x1:Number = 100;
    var y1:Number = 50;
    var x2:Number;
    var y2:Number;
    var centerX:Number = 200;
    var centerY:Number = 200;

    var myAngle:Number = Math.atan2(y1 - centerY, x1-centerX);
    //x2 = x1 + 300 * Math.cos(myAngle);
    //y2 = y1 + 300 * Math.sin(myAngle);
    x2 = centerX + Math.cos(myAngle) * 400;
    y2 = centerY + Math.sin(myAngle) * 400;
    trace("x2,y2 = " + x2 + "," + y2);

    var myCenterPoint:Sprite = new Sprite();
    this.graphics.lineStyle(3,0x00ff00); //green, center point
    this.graphics.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
    graphics.drawCircle(centerX,centerY,5);
    addChild(myCenterPoint);

    var myInnerCirclePointMarker:Sprite = new Sprite();
    this.graphics.lineStyle(3,0x0000FF); //blue, inner circle circumf. marker
    this.graphics.moveTo(x1, y1);
    graphics.drawCircle(x1,y1,5);
    addChild(myInnerCirclePointMarker);

    trace("x2,y2 = " + x2 + "," + y2);
    var myOuterCirclePointMarker:Sprite = new Sprite();
    this.graphics.lineStyle(3,0xff0000); //red, outer circle circumf. marker
    myOuterCirclePointMarker.graphics.drawCircle(x2,y2,5);
    addChild(myOuterCirclePointMarker);

            this.graphics.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
            this.graphics.lineTo(x2, y2);    //draw line, which should go through 
                                             //x1,y1 and end at x2,y2
```

I don't think this is going to correctly show me the outer points along all 360 degrees of the circle.

Thanks.

Comment: Also, your initial values for x1,y1 are not on the inner circle as far as I can tell. You'll still get an angle out of atan2, but your question states the coordinates should be on the inner circle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trig is off here, you shouldn't be multiplying the sin/cos values by 300. You want to draw a line from the centre of circle (centerX, centerY) to x2,y2 (outer circle), but you are using x1,y1 as the centre of your circle. x2,y2 should be calculated from the centre of the circle not from x1,y1 ; Try this

```
var myAngle:Number = Math.atan2(y1 - centerY, x1 - centerX);
x2 = centerX + Math.cos(myAngle) * 400;
y2 = centerY + Math.sin(myAngle) * 400;
var myCircle:Sprite = new Sprite();

this.graphics.lineStyle(3,0x00ff00);
this.graphics.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
this.graphics.lineTo(x2, y2);

myCircle.graphics.drawCircle(x1,y1,5);
addChild(myCircle);
```

The reason your x1,y1 circle isn't appearing is because it's not on the inner circle, which has a bounding box of (100,100),(300,300), i.e. (100,50) isn't in the bounding box.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I edited the code to include your two lines positioning x2 and y2 in place of mine. I also clarified that the 'circle' I was drawing was actually just to mark the position of the centerpoint, not to draw the actual circle (inner or outer) on which the points would be located. I also added markers for the inner circle point (x1, y1) and the outer circle point (x2, y2). I'm not sure what you mean by bounding box of (100,100),(300,300), and how you're coming up with those numbers.

Comment: And what do I  need to do to be able to see all three: the center point, and the two other points? THanks!